# 'run time error 424: object required' after changing function parameter to variant

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a function to find the cell with specific value in a certain range. But I keep getting the 'object required' error on the line: if rng is empty.

This error would not occur if I set the function parameter(searchvalue) type to string, it only occurs if the function parameter(searchvalue) type is variant.

here is my code:

```
Function TgtCell(SearchRange As Range, Optional SearchValue As Variant) As Range
    For Each Rng In SearchRange
        If IsMissing(SearchValue) Then
            If Rng Is Empty Then  'this is the line with the error
                TgtCell = Rng
                Exit For
            End If
        Else
            If Rng.Value = SearchValue Then
                Set TgtCell = Rng
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

below is my test code:

```
Sub test1()
Set Rng = TgtCell(Range([a1:a14], Cells(Rows.Count, 1)))
Rng.Select
End Sub
```

Please help me understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if a cell/range is 'empty' use IsEmpty.

```
Function TgtCell(SearchRange As Range, Optional SearchValue As Variant) As Range
Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In SearchRange
        If IsMissing(SearchValue) Then
            If IsEmpty(rng) Then  'this is the line with the error
                Set TgtCell = rng
                Exit For
            End If
        Else
            If rng.Value = SearchValue Then
                Set TgtCell = rng
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next rng

End Function

Sub test1()
Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = TgtCell(Range([a1:a14], Cells(Rows.Count, 1)))

    rng.Select

End Sub
```